# Relationship between laminar flow, vorticity and vortex formation in a fluid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, vortex, fluid-dynamics

Is it true that for a fluid in **laminar** motion the vorticity is zero?

$$\mathrm{laminar} \implies \, \mathrm{rot} \,\vec{v}=0$$

And is it true that if the vorticity is zero (as in the situation above) vortices do not appear spontaneously in a fluid?

$$ \mathrm{rot} \,\vec{v}=0 \implies \mathrm{no \, spontaneous \, vortices}$$

Answer (score 1):

Laminar flow doesn't mean that the vorticity is zero (rotv⃗ =0), e.g., a rotating non-viscous liquid in a circular container. Your second question depends on the fluid. In inviscid fluids Helmholtz's theorems apply and there should be no spontaneous appearance of vortices. In viscous fluids with boundaries depending on the Reynold's number there can be a spontaneous appearance of eddies (turbulence), depending on the Reynold's number, and therefore rot v⃗ ≠ 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About the first statement, I'm asking this because I see that on some books, when Bernoulli equation is derived (from work - energy theorem), among the assumptions, there is   (beyond stationary flow and perfect fluid of course)  **laminar** flow. If one looks to the derivation from Euler equation instead, the only further condition to impose is that $\mathrm{rot} v=0$ so that the constant of Bernoulli equation **does not depend on the streamline**, so in this context can one assume that saying "laminar" implies that $\mathrm{rot} v=0$?

Comment: When you assume rot v⃗ =0 which is equivalent to v⃗ = grad,  then you restrict the solutions of the Euler equations to velocity fields that have a velocity potential  leading to Bernoullis equation which doesn't depend on the streamline. Then v⃗  is irrotational.  There exist, however,  also solutions to Euler equations with rot v⃗ ≠ 0 that are laminar. So "laminar" does not imply that rot v⃗ =0.

Comment: On the other hand, I assume that rot v⃗ =0 implies that the flow is laminar. With the definition of laminar signifying that fluid particle paths in a stationary flow don't cross, I don't know whether there is a proof for this. Generally,  laminar  is used to characterize a flow that is not turbulent. What definition of "laminar" are you using?.